# Skienna DFS algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

Below is the DFS code provided in Skiena'a Algorithm Design manual.

```
bool processed[MAXV+1]; /* which vertices have been processed */
bool discovered[MAXV+1]; /* which vertices have been found */
int parent[MAXV+1]; /* discovery relation */  
#define MAXV 1000 /* maximum number of vertices */

typedef struct {
int y;                   /* adjacency info */
int weight;             /* edge weight, if any */
struct edgenode *next; /* next edge in list */
} edgenode;

typedef struct {
edgenode *edges[MAXV+1]; /* adjacency info */
int degree[MAXV+1];     /* outdegree of each vertex */
int nvertices;         /* number of vertices in graph */
int nedges;            /* number of edges in graph */
bool directed;        /* is the graph directed? */
} graph;

dfs(graph *g, int v)
{

   edgenode *p;           /* temporary pointer */
   int y;                /* successor vertex */
   if (finished) return; /* allow for search termination */
   discovered[v] = TRUE;
   time = time + 1;
   entry_time[v] = time;
   process_vertex_early(v);
   p = g->edges[v];
   while (p != NULL) {
         y = p->y;
         if (discovered[y] == FALSE) 
         {
             parent[y] = v;
             process_edge(v,y);
             dfs(g,y);
         }
         else if ((!processed[y] && (parent[v]!=y) ) || (g->directed))
             process_edge(v,y);
         if (finished) return;

       p = p->next;

}
   process_vertex_late(v);
   time = time + 1;
   exit_time[v] = time;
   processed[v] = TRUE;
}
```

I feel that the check:

```
else if ((!processed[y] && (parent[v]!=y) ) || (g->directed))
  process_edge(v,y);
```

could simply be:

```
else if ((parent[v]!=y ) || (g->directed))
    process_edge(v,y);
```

I am unable to see how it's possible for `processed[y]` to ever be `true` at this point in code. In a DFS on an undirected graph a node marked processed would have already run through all it's descendants, so just the fact that at that point in code we are reaching `y` through an edge from an as yet unprocessed node, makes it impossible for `y` to be already processed. If the Skiena code is correct, and the `processed[y]` check is necessary for correctness, what am I missing here? Can you present an example where that condition is needed - I am unable to imagine one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary. Let the graph be an undirected loop of three vertices.

The dfs can go in the following order: 1 -> 2 -> 3. When we go back to `1` (after processing `2` and `3`), there is an edge to `3`, but `3` was processed, so the check is necessary.